# Regex to find percent sign with actual math value

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, replace

I have a string like `30+20%`. Now I want to replace `20%` with `(20/100)`. Thats it.

Comment: Can't you simply use `yourString.Replace("%","/100");`?

Comment: @Marco I need the parentheses.

Comment: If you're using math processor, division has higher priority than sum, so it shouldn't be necessary to add parenthesis. Anyway, @Guffa's answer is the one you need.

Comment: @Marco I couldn't agree more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Regex.Replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044353/c-sharp-regex-replace)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the percent doesn't occur in any other situation in the string, you don't even need a regular expression:

```
s = s.Replace("%", "/100");
```

To add the parentheses you need the regular expression though:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d{1,3})%", "($1/100)");
```

Comment: @Guffa Just wanted to ask on a side note what if I change the expression to `30+20.33%`. Your answer doesn't seem to work on those.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: `\d` or `[0-9]` only works on digits, for floating point numbers you have to include the decimal separator also: `[\d\.]`.

Comment: @Guffa I came up with `\d+(\.\d{1,3})`. Match is ok but the replace logic `($1/100)` makes it look like this `30+(.33/100)%`. Just this one bit is gone missing from my head. I must say that the decimal point is optional. So regex should work for both `10+8.33%` and '30+20%' where after replacing it should be `10+(8.33/100)` and `30+(20/100)`. Will my regex be enough for both?

Comment: @Guffa Just came up with this. Please let me know whether this is correct `(\d{1,3}[\.]*\d{0,2})%`

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: I think that `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)%` is better, as it doesn't give false positives for strings like `12345%` or `1.....2%`.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks man. Really good one. Where can I learn good Regex. Point me to some good resource.

Answer (score 3):

```
string s="30+20%";
s=s.Replace("%","/100)");
s=s.Replace("+","+(");
```

Comment: Works well for the given string, but it will mess up strings like `"30-20%"` or `"30+20"`.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just assume you run Perl

```
input="30+20%"
echo $input | perl -pe 's#(\d+)%#\($1/100\)#g'
```

EDIT: just read the tags, anyways, the regex should work in C#

Comment: I just tagged the question with [tag:.net]

Answer (score 1):

That should be an easy regex to try. 1 to 3 digits followed by a percentage sign.
You need to capture the 1-3 digits group for backreference, and use it to create
(DIGITS/100) string.
You can play here :http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to learn regexes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what programming language are you using but this is how you would do this in python:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(\d*)%', r'\1/100', '30+20%')
```

The returned string will be '30+20/100'.

Explanation:
Let's look at the regex. r'\d*%' is a regex that matches a series of digits followed by the % sign. I put paranthesis arount (\d*) to tell the regex compiler that the series of digits (aka the number) is the first group. The second arguemnt tells the sub functions how to replace the matched string. The argument '\1/100' tells the sub function I want it to replace the matched string with the value of the first group matched by the regex (through the \1 part) followed by /100.

You can check the [python re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b(\d+)%", "($1/100)");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```