# How to remove a '-' from text

Tags: c#

How can i remove it ...

```
     static int count = 0;
     string s;
     private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          count++;
          label5.Text = count.ToString("X2");
          DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
          s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +(label5.Text);
          txtSend.Text = s; 
        }
```

How can I get the text from "s" when I press another button and see it in another textbox but without "-" I mean:

```
 s= 4D-1A-2B-3C-label5.text
```

I want it in another textbox by pressing button to see :

```
 4D 1A 2B 3C label5.text
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not very hard:

```
myOtherTextbox.Text = s.Replace('-', ' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that your two textboxes are on the same form, if you want the second text box to be updated when you press another button, then this will do for you

```
private void AnotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtAnotherTextBox.Text = txtSend.Text.Replace('-', ' ');
}
```

and, please, if you really need to share the `s` variable between the form events, give it a meaningful name

Answer (score 0):

Attach the button event to your another button, "txtAnotherTextBox" is your another textbox. And in your case variable 's' is globally declared you can use it.

```
private void anotherButton__Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 txtAnotherTextBox.Text = s.Replace('-', ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
txtSend.Text = s;
```

in your code write:

```
txtSend.Text = s.Replace("-"," ");
```

Or else go with [Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) go though this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1044353/1577396) for more info.